# Error with Generalized portmanteau tests for garch [gBox] in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to use the `gBox()` function from the `TSA` package in R. I want to test the goodness of fit for a GARCH model. But when I try to run the function I get this error message:

> Error in filter(M, filter = beta, method = "recursive", sides = 1,
>   init = rep(sigma2,dims [product 2] do not match the length of object
>   [1]**

The funny thing is that this is from an exact replica of the example that the package instructions provide, so there really shouldn't be any errors one would think. I get the same error message for my own data as well and I just don't know what to do.

Here is the example code:

```
library(TSA)
library(tseries)
data(CREF)
r.cref=diff(log(CREF))*100
m1=garch(x=r.cref,order=c(1,1))
summary(m1)
gBox(m1,x=r.cref,method='squared')
```

The length of the time series r.cref is 500 and the length of the garch m1 is 10, so they're obviously not same length, but how do I fix this error?

Comment: Per the documentation of `gBox`, `gBox(m1,x=r.cref,method='squared')` is commented. I am not sure it is supposed to work...

Comment: Yes I also noticed that. Though it's counter intuitive to provide a non working example. Thanks for looking though!